# Master counter in multiple child loops

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, nested-loops

How can I run a master counter so that I can add it in children's class or content somewhere. I want to add a counter in class of all the `li` elements which will be like `li__1` to `li__n`. The problem here is that they all are in different `ul` and I am running different loops to create the `ul` and `li`.

```js
(function gameOn(n) {

    const gamePad = `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="matrix">
            ${Array(n).fill().map((p, q) => `
                <ul class="row  ${q + 1}">
                    ${Array(n).fill().map((m, n) => `<li class="column ${n+1}"></li>`).join('')}
                </ul>
            `).join('')}            
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    const root = document.getElementById('root')
    root.innerHTML = '';
    root.innerHTML = gamePad;
})(5)
```

```css
html .container .matrix{width:85%;background:#716f71;padding:1rem;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:8px 9px 26px 0 rgba(46,61,73,.5);margin:0 0 3em;overflow:auto}@media(min-width: 768px){html .container .matrix{width:660px;height:660px}}html .container .matrix .row{display:flex;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;margin:0;padding:0}html .container .matrix .row .column{height:4.7rem;width:4.7rem;margin:.2rem .2rem;background:#141214;font-size:0;color:#fff;border-radius:5px;cursor:pointer;box-shadow:5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46,61,73,.5)}@media(min-width: 768px){html .container .matrix .row .column{height:125px;width:125px}}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
(function gameOn(n) {
    let masterCounter=0; 
    const gamePad = `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="matrix">
            ${Array(n).fill().map((p, q) => `
                <ul class="row  ${q + 1}">
                    ${Array(n).fill().map((m, n) => `<li class="column ${n+1} cell">${masterCounter++}</li>`).join('')}
                </ul>
            `).join('')}            
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    const root = document.getElementById('root')
    root.innerHTML = '';
    root.innerHTML = gamePad;
})(5)
```

```css
html .container .matrix {
    width: 85%;
    background: #716f71;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 8px 9px 26px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, .5);
    margin: 0 0 3em;
    overflow: auto
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
    html .container .matrix {
        width: 660px;
        height: 660px
    }
}

html .container .matrix .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

html .container .matrix .row .column {
    height: 4.7rem;
    width: 4.7rem;
    margin: .2rem .2rem;
    background: #141214;
    font-size: 10; // CHANGED
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, .5)
}

.cell {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    html .container .matrix .row .column {
        height: 125px;
        width: 125px
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. :) I got the help from somewhere else already, that's why I didn't check the answer sooner.